# Shorter SQL Statement for similar subqueries using LIMIT and BETWEEN operators

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am adding the results of the subqueries to get one row for january in the code below.

The subqueries are put up the same way. The only thing that changes is the timespan specified in the BETWEEN operator.

Is there a shorter way to write this SQL Statement? Because I also want subqueries for the other months and with this way the SQL for 12 months would become very large.

So in the end I want to add the subqueries to get one row for Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr etc.

(I am using PHP and MySQL.)

Here is the SELECT Statement:

```html
SELECT 
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-01 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-01 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-02 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-02 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-03 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-03 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-04 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-04 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-05 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-05 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-06 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-06 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-07 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-07 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-08 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-08 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-09 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-09 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-10 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-10 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-11 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-11 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-12 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-12 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-13 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-13 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-14 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-14 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-15 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-15 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-16 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-16 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-17 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-17 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-18 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-18 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-19 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-19 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-20 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-20 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-21 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-21 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-22 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-22 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-23 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-23 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-24 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-24 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-25 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-25 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-26 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-26 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-27 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-27 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-28 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-28 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-29 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-29 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-30 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-30 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) +
(
SELECT DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5+DaySum_6+DaySum_7+DaySum_8+DaySum_9+DaySum_15
FROM   rysolarplus
WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-01-31 01:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 23:00:00'
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
LIMIT 1
) AS january;
```

excerpt from table:

[image]

Comment: Could you specify what the table looks like and what the result should look like? Is there a reason why the hours between 23:00 and 01:00 are not counted? Is there a reason why you do not group on YEAR(DatumUhrzeit), MONTH(DatumUhrzeit)?

Comment: @TomasCreemers I always want to get the last row from a day that's why between 01:00 and 23:00 (there's only data during this timespan). Then I want to add these DaySums to get a integer value for each month. In the end i want to have an integer for jan, feb, march etc. I don't really understand what you mean by grouping, because I am still a beginner.

Comment: Are the values always increasing? In other words, is the last row for a given day the same as the maximum for a given day?

Comment: @TomasCreemers yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will take the maximum values of each day and then sum them per month:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(TagTotalen.Tag),
  Month(TagTotalen.Tag),
  SUM(TagTotalen.TagTotal)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DATE(DatumUhrzeit) AS Tag,
      MAX(DaySum_1) + MAX(DaySum_2) AS TagTotal
    FROM
      rysolarplus
    GROUP BY
      DATE(DatumUhrzeit)
  ) AS TagTotalen
GROUP BY
  YEAR(TagTotalen.Tag),
  MONTH(TagTotalen.Tag)
```

SQL Fiddle for demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b73b4/1/0